# I get a FileNotFoundError when I run this Program

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm dealing with moving files from subfolders to another location to organize my Files. While doing so I encountered some errors from this program.

```
import os
from shutil import move

src = "C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\SMALL"
dst = "C:\\ALL IN ONE\\Temporary Folder"

if not os.path.exists(dst):
    os.makedirs(dst)
for x, y, z in os.walk(src):
    for files in z:
        if files.endswith("txt"):
            move(files, dst)
```

When I run the program, it raises a `FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: '0.txt' -> 'C:\\ALL IN ONE\\Temporary Folder\\0.txt'` error and a bunch of other "`Traceback Errors`" (if that's what they're called)

Comment: Is ```C:\\ALL IN ONE\\Temporary Folder``` the real path, or just a placeholder?

Comment: The real path, It's the "Another Location" that i'm talking about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to construct the source path.  Try changing:

```
move(files, dst)
```

to:

```
path = os.path.join(x, files)
move(path, dst)
```

You might also want to rename `files` to `file`, since it's just a single file each time through the loop.

Justin Ezequiel pointed out that including `src` in the call to `os.path.join` is incorrect, so I've updated the answer to simply join `x` and `files`.

Comment: Consider `path = os.path.join(x, files)`. The src is not needed.

Comment: OHH, Thank You it worked! If you don't mind would you expound a little bit on the "os.path.join" part of the code?

Comment: @Clorky `os.path.join` just concatenates its arguments into a path, in a way that your OS wants to see it.  The components are separated by `os.sep`, which on Windows would be `'\\'`.  You can test it - type `os.path.join("C:\\x\\y", "z\\w", "a")` for example, and you'll get `"C:\\x\\y\\z\\w\\a"`.

Comment: @TomKarzes, if you add prints, you'll see that x already includes the src prefix.

Comment: @TomKarzes OHH, Okay okay it makes sense now why I couldn't move it. Thanks much!

Comment: Also works with relative paths. Whatever you pass as the 1st argument to os.walk gets prepended to root where root is x in the OP's code. I always use `for root, dirs, files in os.walk(...)` as in the examples in the docs.

Comment: @JustinEzequiel Ah ok, yeah that makes sense.  So yeah, `src` should never be explicitly included.

Comment: @Clorky I've updated my answer based on Justin's comments.  You should use the updated answer, which just has `os.path.join(x, files)`, i.e. remove `src` from the argument list.